# Using nested dictionaries in text mining

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, text-mining

I have a nested dictionary structured as follows:

```
rules = 
 {'conjugation': {'v0': {'ending': 'cer'}},
 {'v1': {'ending': 'er'}},

...

}
```

What I want to do is take a list of words, find all of it's endings, and get the ruleID associated with that ending.

I would need to take the most restrictive ending, for example, a word like "déplacer" would need to show v0 even if v1 also fits, as v0's ending is longer.

Any ideas ? Thank you

Comment: Please complete your example dict with some `}`

Comment: Maybe convert the dict to a suffix-tree?

Comment: Never used those, how would it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trie for that and score then score the result by the length of the matched keys.

You first index *conjugation* using the reverse string of the suffix:

```
In [1]: import pygtrie

In [2]: trie = pygtrie.CharTrie()

In [3]: trie['re'] = 'v0'

In [4]: trie['rec'] = 'v1'
```

Then you can query for conjugation using the following code:

```
In [22]: list(trie.prefixes(''.join(reversed('aimer'))))
Out[22]: [('re', 'v0')]

In [23]: list(trie.prefixes(''.join(reversed('balancer'))))
Out[23]: [('re', 'v0'), ('rec', 'v1')]
```

Then you can score the result using a simple function like this:

```
In [24]: best = lambda candidates: sorted(candidates, key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True)[0]

In [25]: best(trie.prefixes(''.join(reversed('balancer'))))
Out[25]: ('rec', 'v1')
```